# How to avoid drngjava.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator error in spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hello I would like to know how to avoid the following error next on empty iterator error in spark Dataframe. In fact I would like to apply a condition only when my dataframe is not empty.

Here is my code sample:

for (arsdcolname <- columns) {
var arsdcolnameLower = arsdcolname.replace(".","*").replace("[","*").replace("]","").toLowerCase()
if (datasource0.columns.contains(arsdcolnameLower)) {

```
    var df = datasourceMs.select("vi","timestamp","filename",arsdcolnameLower) //.withColumn("timestamp",to_timestamp(col("timestamp")).cast(LongType))
    print("VAR : ("+arsdcolname+")")
    var colname = arsdcolname
    var arsd_label_1d = ""
    var arsd_index_1d = 0.0
    var arsd_value_1d = ""
    var arsd_label_2d = ""
    var arsd_index_2d = 0.0
    var arsd_value_2d = ""
    var arsd_label_3d = ""
    var arsd_index_3d = 0.0
    var arsd_value_3d = ""
    var arsd_idx_1 = 0
    var arsd_idx_2 = 0
    if (colname.contains("Ics_Nvm_Data")) colname = colname.replace("Ics_Nvm_Data_2","Ics_Nvm_Data").split("Ics_Nvm_Data.")(1) 
    var configFound = false 
    var rowConfig = ARSDConfig.first()
  
  if (!(ARSDConfig.filter(col("colname") === colname.toLowerCase().split('[')(0)).isEmpty)) {
  configFound = true
  var rowConfig =  ARSDConfig.filter(col("colname") === colname.toLowerCase().split('[')(0)).first()
    }  
    
    else if (colname.contains("[") && !(ARSDConfig.filter(col("colname") === colname.toLowerCase().split('[')(0).concat("[").concat(colname.toLowerCase().split('[')(1))).isEmpty)) {
        configFound = true
        rowConfig = ARSDConfig.filter(col("colname") === colname.toLowerCase().split('[')(0).concat("[").concat(colname.toLowerCase().split('[')(1))).first()
    }
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
VAR : (variable name)drngjava.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator at 
scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37) at 
scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:63) at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.head(IterableLike.scala:107)
enter code here
```

Any help is welcome

Best regards

Comment: here is the error that I get:

VAR : (variable name)drngjava.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:63)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.head(IterableLike.scala:107)

Comment: Can u put code preceding this in pls?

Comment: Hello, thebluephantom, I have edited the code and put the code preceeding. In fact when I change the paramater  "configFound = true" into "configFound = false", there is no excetion anymore. So I think that the exception is raised by  "configFound = true". Is there a why to pass when the dataframe is empty ?                                              Best regards and thank you for your help

Comment: An empty DF therefore?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "An empty DF therefore?"